# Automation Studio Repeat Every 10 minutes

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I need to automate an activity to run every 10 minutes. I was able to schedule earlier as every minutes option was available (see attached) now I can not see this minutes option at all.

Do  I need to contact Salesforce reactivate it.

[image]

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132071/can-automation-studio-be-scheduled-less-than-once-a-hour

Answer (score 2):

From everything I have heard, inside the UI it can only go down to run once every 1 hour.  SFMC support has told me that the system is set up this way and there is no possible way to do this directly in Automation Studio. Maybe they are working on changing this soon and you got a 'sneak peak' of it by accident?

The recommended solution we have implemented is to create a 3rd party automation to send an API call to SFMC to run the unscheduled automation every 10 minutes.

[reference for API calls to Automation Studio](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/interacting-with-automation-studio-via-the-web-service-soap-api.html)

Comment: I've heard stories from partners of them being able to have support alter the scheduling down to minutes. I've never bothered trying but I imagine support would be hesitant, like with upping the query timeout limit, so you would need a good use-case and negotiation skills.