# T-SQL Automation Studio activity by minutes period

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, activity

I see there's no option to automate and run an sql activity in frequency of XY minutes... The shortest unit of time is the hour (hh). I know the T-SQL query supports the mi,n for minutes. But the Automation Builder only start from hour... So jobs only could be repeated each hour but not less. Is there any other way to automate a T-SQL query to run less than 1 hour period?

Comment: I see this is very similar. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132071/can-automation-studio-be-scheduled-less-than-once-a-hour?rq=1

Comment: This seems is what I'm looking for. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api.htm?search_text=perform Thanks

Comment: create two automation then first one time is like 11:30 and second one like 12:00  that time it will run every half hour